# Flush all memory on reload in NW.js

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, chromium, node-webkit, nw.js

I'm porting a huge angular.js / node App to NW.js.  Everything was fine until I checked the memory usage of the App.
When the app started, the **nwjs Helper** process consumed 75MB.
After the first reload -using `location.reload()` or `win.reload()`- the memory usage rose to 110MB.  Second reload, 125MB. Third Reload, 155 MB, Fourth reload, 180 MB. Fifth reload, 205 MB, Sixth reload 235 MB... and so on. At 20 or 25 reloads the app crashed.
The app have child node processes that mantain their memory usage stable in 30MB across reloads.
There is no context shared between node and chrome, all the communication between node and chrome processes is done using localStorage.
The same angular app running on Chrome as a web app doesn't have any memory leaks and the memory start at zero in each reload.

I found a partial solution using `chrome.runtime.reload()` but the problem is that it not only refresh the chrome view but all child processes (is like quit and restart the app).  I need to mantain the node processes running when main view is refreshed.  I read in forums that many people have the same problem with memory leaks appearing when navigating from page to other page in the chrome webview. I tried erasing all the memory node by node before reload and nothing happens (using a Black Hole program from Robert CMoses Kałamański). I tried using `global.gc()` with `"js-flags": "--expose-gc"`and nothing happened.

I made another simple app with only a couple of variables, and the same memory leak appeared when reload.  I tried the NW.js demo app (when you just run `nwjs` without any parameters) and it appears a gray screen with nw, chrome and node versions. If you right-click-Reload App some times at this simple page, the memory usage will also rise... OMG!!!!

**Is there any way of flush all the memory of the chrome view in NW.JS just before unload the window when reloading? Is there any secure way of erasing all javascript object and DOM nodes?** Or is this a bug of NW.js memory management?

I'm using NW.js v 0.19.4

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure there is no reference to the DOM objects in the Node context. The Node context lives in the background page and keeps running throughout the application's lifetime. To do that use the heap profiler in the devtools to find out what objects is referred.

Another way is to use the "mixed context" mode, where Node context and DOM context is the same.

See more here: http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/JavaScript%20Contexts%20in%20NW.js/

Comment: I tried everything you mentioned, without results.  As I posted, if you make a very simple app without accessing node and start reloading, your memory will increase after each reload.  Try with the landing page of nwjs, you will get this same error.

Comment: Roger, I will really appreciatte your support here.  I have also two senior members of my team investigating this issue without any news, and if we can't find a solution we will have to move to electron (not of my taste, but without this memory leak problem, as far as we investigated in forums). The app is built on angular js 1.5 and is huge in code (Restaurant App with more than 300 restaurants using it, check Toteat).  The app have node processes listening http request on port 80 and socket in por 8080. All the communication is done through localStorage and the data is saved in websql.

Comment: @ReneMarty you can report an issue with the simple app attached. I'll see it soon.